# Streaming an .flv video From php is not working, using flow player and video js

Tags: php, apache, streaming, video-streaming, flowplayer

i was trying to add video play back in my website..

How did i tried it ?
  the video's to be played is not in my websites Document root, but instead it is outside Doc root so i can't name a file to be played like **example.com/video/vid1.flv** , instead what i am doing is using the url **example.com/video/index.php?id=hngthf**  to get data, and inside this php file i do

```
                //Video Streaming
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Type: video/flv');
            //header('Content-Disposition:attachment; filename=' . $justName);
            header('Content-length: ' . filesize($fileName));
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
            $file = fopen($fileName, 'r');
            echo stream_get_contents($file);    
            //echo file_get_contents($fileName);
            fclose($file);
```

then on the client side, i tried to use videojs and flow player but with no luck, lets see  how i used these players

**Video js**

```
var myPlayer = _V_("myVideo",{"techOrder" : ["flash"], "controls" : true, "autoplay" : false, "preload": "auto"});
            _V_.options.flash.swf = "../scripts/video-js.swf"
            myPlayer.src('../index.php?id=' + code);
            //myPlayer.src('../my.flv');
            myPlayer.load(); 
            myPlayer.play();
```

Video js error message : 
    *Video Error *V*.Event {type: "error", timeStamp: 1362567722368, vdata1362567711568: true, preventDefault: function, stopPropagation: function…} video.js:21 Flash Error srcnotfound myVideo_flash_api*

```
even though it says src not found, it actually hit my php  and getting executed
```

and then **flow player**

**Step-1**

```
flowplayer("player", "../scripts/flowplayer-3.2.16.swf", {
                plugins: {
                    secure: {
                        url: '../scripts/flowplayer.securestreaming-3.2.8.swf'
                    }   
                },

                clip: {
                    provider: 'http',
                    url: '../index.php?id=' + code
                }
            });
```

Flow player error message: 
    *200, Stream not found, NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound, clip:*

**Step-2**

```
var videoURL = "index.php?id=" + code;
            //var videoURL = "my.flv";
            var htmll = '<object width="640" height="264" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="../scripts/flowplayer-3.2.16.swf">';
            htmll += '<param name="wmode" value="transparent"/><param name="movie" value="../scripts/flowplayer.securestreaming-3.2.8.swf" />';
            htmll += '<param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />';
            htmll += '<param name="flashvars" value=\'config={"playlist":[{"url": "' + videoURL + '", "baseUrl": "http://localhost", "autoPlay":false,"autoBuffering":true,"bufferLength":5}]}\' /></object>';
            $("#videoTag").html(htmll);

Flow player  error message : 
*200 stream not found Netstream.play.StreamNotFound, clip:*
```

Note:
    i use Apache, php, mysql on Server(Localhost also tried on production server), also installed mod_flvx and client is chromium on Ubuntu 12.04  also tried firefox

1, also tried adding types in apache
     #AddType video/flv .flv
      AddType video/x-flv .flv 
     #AddType video/x-flv flv

2, in php, $fileName, i kept a flv file in Doc root  and tried getting it from php script but no luck

3, in all the above client example's, instead of giving .php  if i give a direct .flv file in my server, then it works

4, as you can see commented code above, those are my trial and error ... i tried a lot, No Luck

Comment: Why are you doing this in the first place? Do you have some sort of access control in your PHP script?

Comment: @ Pekka it is bit of both, First the real flv file is outside Document root, actually in a mounted NFS File server, also i dont want to give direct access to the video file, thats why it is through php

Comment: This is very resource-intensive on the server's end because a costly PHP process has to run the entire time. If you're not actually doing a login check of some sort, maybe it might be worth thinking about alternatives like symlinks?

Comment: i am doing a Login check, and also checks the user has permission to view the given video.